# How to get an NSNumber from a String of decimal?

Tags: swift, foundation

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but `NumberFormatter` fails to get a number from a simple decimal `String` when using the `number(from:)` method.

Here's an example:

```swift
let decimalString: String = "12.5"
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let number = formatter.number(from: decimalString)
print(number) // nil
```

Please keep in mind that I'm using `NumberFormatter` to handle decimals from any locale, so passing `"١٢٫٥"` should also lead to a non-nil return value from `number(from:)`.

What is the correct and locale-aware way of converting any string from a `UITextField` that is entered using keyboard type `.decimalPad` to a valid `NSNumber` and get the `doubleValue` from it? (shortcuts like using the `Double` initializer or the `.asciiCapableNumberPad` keyboard type are not ideal)

Comment: "handle decimals from any locale" That's not possible. What should "123.456" mean? The dot in different locales mean different things. If this is from an `UITextField`, don't you just want to handle the *current* locale?

Comment: If you set the locale property of the formatter to `.current` and the user inputs a string according to this locale it should work

Comment: The user could have multiple keyboards of different languages (For example Arabic and English) and could switch the keyboard to a different language than the current locale which will have a different decimal separator. What's the best way to handle this case?